# How many levels are there in Implosion?

Tags: android, implosion

Implosion is a free download (at least, it is for Android). The free version is essentially a trial, allowing you to play the first 6 levels of the campaign repeatedly. But, the campaign trail only displays levels you've unlocked, plus the next unlockable level that's grayed out and unselectable. Since the game costs $10 USD, I'd like to know just how much gameplay there is for my 10 dollars.

How many levels are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are **34** levels in Implosion. I got this from [The Implosion wikia](http://implosion.wikia.com/wiki/Chapters)

Comment: Nice find on the wiki, I hadn't located that page yet.

Comment: Alright @Ellesedil, I'm glad it helped =)

Comment: By the way, if my answer was right and helped, mind clicking the check mark, it really helps @Ellesedil

Comment: I'm well aware. I generally like to hold off on accepting answers right away on new question just in case other good answers are out there.

Comment: Alright @Ellesedil, I hope my answer helped still